# React+Electron: Building web & desktop app at the same time with different behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I need to build a website using React and a desktop app for a university project.

They are supposed to have very simillar functionality, so I thought about using Electron.

The main difference is that when using electron I need to have a "download" button in some areas, and a few other webpages ("my downloads" and "upload a file").

1. Is it possible to easiliy share the frontend code between them,without copying the react code from one to the other each time it is updated?
2. I thought about having in my React code something akin to

```
if (running on electron)
    displayAdditionalPages()

if (running on electron)
    fetchDownloadsProgress()
```

but couldn't find how to do it. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/cheton/is-electron

Comment: Find whether device is desktop or mobile and work on it... https://medium.com/simplejs/detect-the-users-device-type-with-a-simple-javascript-check-4fc656b735e1